# I am trying to Pull data from another sheet based on drop down selection in another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So, I have sheetA that has a drop down available and I want to show value for stock in a cell but the data is in another sheet.

Say I have four items. Carrot, Potato, Tomato, Lettuce and this is available to choose as a Drop Down in Cell B1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZRpI.png)

What is the formula to show stock in Cell A2 pulling stock data from Sheet B

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Xjce.png)

I am super new to excel and trying to learn. I don't know if this is a VLOOKUP, Choose, IF function

Comment: VLOOKUP will likely do what you want

Comment: Lot of examples, sure will resolve your issue, check **[VLOOKUP](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4851590+VLOOKUP+)**